# Android AVD doesn't start up

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I used the ARM based CPU.
I get the following Error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_One_by_Google'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I have used the platform 4.2.2 API level 10.
i have used 768Mb of Ram.

Please Help me !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have all the SDKs and necessary AVD files installed?